# Is it possible to update a nested Oracle table in PL/SQL using SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I would think this is possible, but I can't find any examples of how to update a nested table in a PL/SQL block using SQL.  I am loading a nested table with rows and now I want to update values in multiple rows without having to iterate through the table, checking values, and then setting them.  I'd prefer to issue a SQL statement.

I know this is kind of a silly example, but I'm just trying to provide a simple example...

```
CREATE TYPE my_rec AS OBJECT (col1 NUMBER, col2 NUMBER, col3 NUMBER);
CREATE TYPE my_tab AS TABLE OF my_rec;

DECLARE
   plstab my_tab := my_tab(NULL,NULL,NULL);
BEGIN
   SELECT my_rec(x,y,z)
   BULK COLLECT INTO plstab
   FROM data_table;
   -- Now I want to update plstab using SQL and set
   -- y = x*10 and z = x+y where x > 10
   -- This won't work...how would I do something like this?
   UPDATE plstab
   SET y = x*10, 
       z = x+y
   WHERE x>10;
END;
```

Comment: The error you get when you try to run this isi:  ORA-00942 table or view does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest workaround will be manipulating the SQL first and then do the BULK COLLECT. I have illustrated an example below. Please pardon any syntax error as i dont have workspace with me now.

```
DECLARE
   plstab my_tab := my_tab();
BEGIN
SELECFCT my_rec(x,y,z)
BULK COLLECT INTO plstab
FROM
(SELECT x, CASE WHEN X> 10 THEN (X*10) 
        ELSE Y END Y,
         CASE WHEN X> 10 THEN (X+ (CASE WHEN X> 10 THEN (X*10) 
        ELSE Y END)) Z
FROM data_table);

END;
```

Comment: I think you are missing the point.  I am trying to see if it is possible to "update" a PLSQL table.  Imagine the table was populated using many more steps and much more complex logic where it was not possible to select the "updated" data into the table.  Basically I cam constructing a piplelined function and I need to be able to construct the output in a PLSQL table for output.

Comment: Yes, you can do what you want, in fact some version of it is the norm not an exception. In your case the "select.. bulk collect..." is merely a process for populating a plsql collection. Once populated all collections functions are available as are assignment statements. See collections in t0he plsql reference manual.